# Logs monitoring via CWagent / Alert / How to identify the instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I'd like to ask you for a help.

I've just configured the CloudWatch agent in order to monitor the Linux system logs e.g. /var/log/messages. Furthermore I've also configured the CloudWatch Alarm which should be triggered every time the "error" string is detected in system logs.

I see that the logs are already present in the CloudWatch dashboard, also I've got the email SNS notification that the "error" is detected in log file while I was testing it,
BUT:

**I don't see any =instance identification, =any Log groups identification, =any Log stream idenfitication in the notification/alerting E-mail I received...**

So How can I identify the instance with "errors" if I miss such info -> Let's imagine that I would run 20 EC2 ???

I would really appreciate any hint which could move me into the right direction...

Screensthots:

https://petybucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/upload/aws1.PNG

https://petybucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/upload/aws2.png

https://petybucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/upload/aws3.PNG

Thanks in advance

Peter

Comment: Can you share some screenshots of your setup?

Comment: Hi, I've attached screenshots.. thnx

Comment: The second link is broken

Comment: Sorry, Link is now fixed.

Comment: CW metrics filter doesn't allow you to include this info. You can stream logs to lambda and send alarms there.